# Compile error: undefined reference to

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Im trying to run the code thats is available in the bottom of this page: http://www.rolfmuertter.com/code/nw.php (main.cpp, nw.cpp and nw.h). But im getting the following error when i try to compile:

main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1b9): undefined reference to`nw(std::string, std::string, std::string&, std::string&, bool)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1e4): undefined reference to `print_al(std::string&, std::string&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Any sugestions?

Comment: How do you compile the program? What OS and compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I could compile it with the below line so you probably need to add nw.cpp to the compiler line. This is clang.

```
clang++ -Wall -o nw main.cpp nw.cpp
```